# How to click the next span value which has same class name

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
import urllib3
import certifi
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import ssl
http = urllib3.PoolManager(ca_certs=certifi.where())
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path="D:\\python works\\driver\\chromedriver.exe")
URL= "https://physicians.wustl.edu/"
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Find a Doctor").click()
find_doc = driver.current_url
print(find_doc)
driver.get(find_doc)
# content = driver.page_source
# print(content)
response = http.request('GET', find_doc)
url_text = response.data  #text
time.sleep(10)
count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='entry-title-link']"))
print(count)
s = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class='entry-title-link']")  #firstpage click
s.click()
urls = []
provider = []
print(driver.current_url)
urls.append(driver.current_url)
name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1[class='washu-ppi-name entry-title']").text
print(name)
provider.append(name)
specialization = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul[class='wuphys-specialties']").text
print(specialization)
location= driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='wuphys-addr name']").text
print(location)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='https://physicians.wustl.edu/find-a-doctor/']").click()
time.sleep(10)
```

I have same classname of span but I need to loop the same class name but the div is different. In the url there is doctors name with details after click I get details and I need to move to next doctor which has same class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something of this kind (to loop through all the doctor links and get info from there). Here I have written a basic action which you can scale to add more data related to each doctor.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path="D:\\python works\\driver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://physicians.wustl.edu/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Find a Doctor"))).click()
print(driver.current_url)
doc_cnt = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='entry-title-link']")))
print(len(doc_cnt))

doc_list=[]  # to append all the doctor urls into the list for further processing, if required.
for doc in doc_cnt:
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(doc).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    doc_list.append(driver.current_url)
    # ... you could include any code of yours related to each doctor here...
    # After this one the tab terminates and a new doctor link would open
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    time.sleep(1)
print(doc_list)
```